# autoreload partial every few seconds ala twitter search style

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can i autoreload every few seconds a partial, just like in twitter seach. i am using rails and hobo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing to use in Rails is `periodically_call_remote` . Example from [Agile Web Development with Rails, Third Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356166)
 follows:

```
<div id="inbox_status">Unknown</div>
<%= periodically_call_remote :url => {:action => 'get_inbox_status',
:user_id => @user.id},
:update => 'inbox_status',
:frequency => 60,
:condition => "$('inbox_status').innerHTML == 'Unknown'" ,
:before => "Element.show('progress_indicator')" ,
:complete => "Element.hide('progress_indicator')" %>
```

Comment: With a little work you can cut down on the processing time, by passing the time the page was rendered at and only fetching/returning only the new updates since the last poll.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there is no common approach to do this kind of stuff. As I imagine, you would need to asynchronously query the server for updates every once in a while, but it can become quite cumbersome for the server if there are many clients polling for new data all the time.

I would suggest using something like [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/) to maintain a constant connection to the server and get fresh data as soon as it is available.

Answer (score 0):

It may be time to roll up your sleeves and view source. I've heard of folks using [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) to keep a live server connection open for such real-time things.